# dynamically align images to maximum 3 on desktop and 2 on mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an upload component that previews selected images before the user can upload them to the server.

I want to display a maximum of 3 on the desktop and a maximum of 2 on the tablet and 1 on the mobile.

I don't know how many images the user will upload so it is a dynamic amount.

An example of an upload would generate something like this for 4 files.

```
<div>
  <div>
     <div class="thumbnail">
       <div class="caption">
         <h3>
           <span>fixed_bug.png</span>
          </h3>
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive">Delete</a>
          </p>
       </div>
       <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3030/62733983-bb74-494c-bd4e-7a66ccfcb463" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><span>obomber.jpg</span></h3>
        <p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive">Delete</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3030/498e5d16-114e-41b5-8d4d-4e798c36861c" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="thumbnail>
      <div class="caption">
        <h3><span>podcasts.png</span></h3>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive">Delete</a></p>
      </div>
      <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3030/08a89a31-6822-4436-a8be-e89ddfee9f0f" class="img-thumbnail">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
       <div class="caption">
         <h3><span>tangents.png</span></h3>
         <p>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive">Delete</a>
         </p>
       </div>
       <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3030/ae1c844f-f0d2-4a50-a0b1-c46b4c00a4ba" class="img-thumbnail">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Not sure about your requirement. But use Bootstrap GRID system to display your images in `div` using classes as `.col-lg-4` for desktop and `.col-md-6` for tablet and `col-xs-12` for mobile

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja would this be added to the div that contains all the images or for the div that contains the image

Comment: Every image must be place in single div with bootstrap classes. The below answer works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as some said in a comment use the bootstrap grid system, very useful and this can all be achieved by doing using this

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Here is something that you might be able to use sorry on my phone at the moment might be rough:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>
                     <span>fixed_bug.png</span>
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive">Delete</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3030/62733983-bb74-494c-bd4e-7a66ccfcb463" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>
                     <span>fixed_bug.png</span>
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive">Delete</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3030/62733983-bb74-494c-bd4e-7a66ccfcb463" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>
                     <span>fixed_bug.png</span>
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-responsive">Delete</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <img src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3030/62733983-bb74-494c-bd4e-7a66ccfcb463" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```